# mongoose: .find() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

None of the already existing posts on Stackoverflow have remedied my issue. I have the following in the router:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./users/models");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(express.json());

router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    console.log(username);
    User.find({ username: username })
        .then(user => res.json(user.serialize()))
        .then(res => console.log(res));
});

module.exports = router;
```

with the following Schema:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  firstName: { type: String, default: "" },
  lastName: { type: String, default: "" },
  bases: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "UserVariables" }],
});

const UserVariables = mongoose.Schema({
  bases: { type: "String", required: true },
  users: [{ type: String }],
});
const UserVariable = mongoose.model("UserVariable", UserVariables);
const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = { User, UserVariable };
```

When running the server, the .find() method returns an error message stating: `TypeError: User.find is not a function`. I tried several different versions in the router:

```
router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    User.find({ username: username }, user => {
        console.log(user);
    });
```

as well as:

```
User.findOne({ username: username })
        .then(user => res.json(user.serialize()))
        .then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

Neither of which works. In another App i am running the former and it works just fine. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting an object:

> `module.exports = { User, UserVariable };`

So to use `User.find(...)` from your require, you should call `User.User.find(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exchanging User with UserVariable.

```
UserVariable.findOne({ username: username })
        .then(user => res.json(user.serialize()))
        .then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

Comment: UserVariable does not contain the username and can therefore not be used. I just tried it anyway and it throws the same error message

Comment: The problem is that the `User` model is exported as a property on an object, not as a top level object. This just changes the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
module.exports=User=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema)
```

instead of

```
module.exports = router;
```